# How to design a data structures to fit customize sort?

Tags: java, database

There are some items in a table, I hope that user can define the sort of these items by himself.
So I add a field `sortValue (Int )` to the table, the table maybe

```
name   sortValue
Jack       3
Paul       1
April      30
Alic       25
```

And I use the following code to display items sort by use defined.

```
Select name, sortValue from myTable order by sortValue
```

The result will be

```
name   sortValue
Paul       1
Jack       3
Alic       25
April      30
```

I find it's hard to change the order of these items by the data structures .

For example:

I hope the record `(name=Alic, sortValue=25)` is at the second position. I have to update the record as `(name=Alic,  sortValue=2)`.

The result will be

```
name   sortValue
Paul       1
Alic       2
Jack       3
April      30
```

If I need the record `(name=April, sortValue=30)` is at the second position next time, I find I have no sortValue for the record!

Comment: Can’t you just exchange two values instead of creating a new each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use floating point type for `sortValue` column, thus you'll always have a space to insert a new value between two others.

```
# if record is between others 
sortValue = (prevSortValue + nextSortValue)/2

# if record is last
sortValue = prevSortValue + 1
```

It is theoretically possible to meet the same problem as with integers when you run out of floating point precision. But in practice it highly depends on how often do you insert records between others. Especially when you have lot of inserts near the same record.

Updating existing records just to put a new record in correct place seems very inefficient because `update` is much more expensive operation than `insert` and requires locking for records, that you do not suppose to modify.

Comment: This works ok, except that if you want to change someone's order to 3, you now have to find the existing second and third entries, and then insert this one at (2nd+3rd)/2. Works ok, provided you can easily find those 2nd and 3rd rows (which of course you can with row_number() for example).

Comment: Thanks!   Is there any more better way?

Comment: The related question is how to generate the value of `sortValue` for every record. use random function to fill in ?  or prevSortValue +10000.00 for new record?